# I have problem in insert data into database but didn't show any error

Tags: php

I have problem with inserting my data into database 
usually if something wrong it's showing error but this one not showing error (I don't know if this count as error or not cause I'm still new with this php coding stuff)

```
<?php
    /*proses*/

    $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','root', '','dsolo');
    // Check connection
    if (!$conn) {

    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }




        $id = $_POST['id'];
        $bulan = $_POST['bulan'];
        $gajipokok = $_POST['gajipokok'];
        $totalbonus = $_POST['totalbonus'];
        $potongan = $_POST['potongan'];
        $totalgaji = $_POST['totalgaji'];
        $pajak = $_POST['pajak'];
        $tes="INSERT INTO gaji set id='$id',
                                   bulan='$bulan',
                                   gajipokok='$gajipokok',
                                   totalbonus='$totalbonus',
                                   potongan='$potongan',
                                   totalgaji='$totalgaji',
                                   pajak='$pajak',";
        mysqli_query ($conn,$tes) or die ($tes);

?>
```

After I press save what is showing is this one instead

```
INSERT INTO gaji set id='yuki', bulan='2019-08', gajipokok='2000000', totalbonus='2000000', potongan='1000000', totalgaji='3000000', pajak='300000',
```

What I need to change in my code?

Comment: Your query ending with `,`  maybe it is creating a problem for you

Comment: @AnkurTiwari
Yeah after I delete `,` its solved my problem 
Thanks for the guide. btw how do I change this topic as answered and mark vote up your comment?

Comment: Great happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an extra `,` in your query, you can remove that and your code look like the below code..

```
<?php
     $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','root', '','dsolo');
     // Check connection
     if (!$conn) 
     {
         die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
     }
     else
     {
         $id = $_POST['id'];
         $bulan = $_POST['bulan'];
         $gajipokok = $_POST['gajipokok'];
         $totalbonus = $_POST['totalbonus'];
         $potongan = $_POST['potongan'];
         $totalgaji = $_POST['totalgaji'];
         $pajak = $_POST['pajak'];
         $tes="INSERT INTO gaji set id='$id', bulan='$bulan', gajipokok='$gajipokok', totalbonus='$totalbonus',potongan='$potongan', totalgaji='$totalgaji', pajak='$pajak'";
         mysqli_query ($conn,$tes) or die ($tes);
    }

?>
```

Comment: You can put some explanation here what you have done in the answer

Comment: if you get your answer and its helpful for you so please give upvote so other people refer this answer thank you !.